# Q.ninvoke not able to handle the response

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, youtube-api

I make the function that download the youtube video and upload it to s3.
But I am facing one problem in that .If I use Q.all for uploading video to s3 it work fine but If I used Q.ninvoke in the place of Q.all it always fail to handle the success response and give error `object has no method apply`

```
function checkYoutubeRecord(youtubeRecords){
var totalCount = youtubeRecords.length;
var count = 0;
(function downloadLoop(record){
    if(record.Size > 0){
            if(count === totalCount-1){
                console.log('\n\n\ncomplete downloading\n\n\n');
            }else{
                count = count + 1;
                downloadLoop(youtubeRecords[count]);
            }
    }else{
        /*If the size of the record is zero then if don't need to check if it exist
        in the log or not as we have to upload it because of zero size*/
        downloadYoutubeVideo(record,function(done){
            if(done){
                var removeMp2 = record.Key.split('.');
                var removePath = removeMp2[0].split('/');
                **// If use Q.ninvoke throw error Object has no method apply**
                Q.all([
                uploadS3.uploadToS3( __dirname + '/tmp/' + removePath[1] + ".mp4",'/videoTestmp4')])
                .spread(function(uploads){
                    console.log('\n\n\n********************************************');
                    console.log('uploaded successfully==========>>>>>>',record);
                    console.log('********************************************\n\n\n');
                    fs.unlink( __dirname + '/tmp/' + removePath[1] + ".mp4", function(err) {
                        if( err ){
                            console.log(err);
                            console.log('error in unlinking of'+ removePath[1] + '.mp4 file');
                        }else{
                            console.log('successfully removed from tmp folder'+ removePath[1] + '.mp4 file');
                        }
                    });
                    loggerSuccess.info(youtubeRecords[count]);
                    if(count === totalCount-1){
                        console.log('\n\n\ncomplete downloading\n\n\n');
                    }else{
                        count = count + 1;
                        downloadLoop(youtubeRecords[count]);
                    }
                })
                .fail(function(err){
                    console.log('\n\n\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
                    console.error('fail in uploading the ogv and mp3',record);
                    console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n\n');
                    if(failureCount <= 3){
                        failureCount = failureCount + 1;
                        downloadLoop(youtubeRecords[count]);
                    }else{
                        failureCount = 0;
                        loggerfailure.info(youtubeRecords[count]);
                        count = count + 1;
                        downloadLoop(youtubeRecords[count]);
                    }
                })
            }else{
                console.log('\n\n\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
                console.error('fail in uploading the ogv and mp3',record);
                console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n\n');
                if(failureCount <= 3){
                    failureCount = failureCount + 1;
                    downloadLoop(youtubeRecords[count]);
                }else{
                    failureCount = 0;
                    loggerfailure.info(youtubeRecords[count]);
                    count = count + 1;
                    downloadLoop(youtubeRecords[count]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
})(youtubeRecords[0]);
}
```

**Module for uploading the video to s3**

```
var path = require('path') ;
var AWS = require('aws-sdk') ;
var fs = require('fs') ;
var Q = require('q');

module.exports =  {
  uploadToS3: function(file, s3folder){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: "********************",
        secretAccessKey: "*******************"
    });

    var filename = path.basename( file ) ;
    var key = s3folder + "/" + filename ;

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    s3.listObjects({
        Bucket: '****************',
        MaxKeys: 10,
        Prefix: key
    }, function(err, data) {

            console.log('\n\n\n********************************************');
            console.log('source =====>>>>',file);
            console.log('S3 destination ',key);
            console.log('********************************************\n\n\n');

            fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
                s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: '****************',
                    Key: key,
                    Body: data,
                    ACL: 'public-read'
                }, function(err, response) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log('\n\n\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
                        console.log('errror =>>>>',err);
                        console.log('file fail to upload ',file);
                        console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n\n');
                        deferred.reject(err);
                    }
                    console.log('\n\n\n********************************************');
                    console.log('response =>>>>',response);
                    console.log('s3 destination ',key);
                    console.log('successfully uploaded to s3');
                    console.log('********************************************\n\n\n');
                    deferred.resolve('uploaded');

                });
            });
    });
return deferred.promise;
}
};
```